# Maximum length of string literals in Scheme

Tags: string, scheme, language-lawyer

Is there a maximum length for string literals in Scheme? Or is it dependent on Scheme implementation? In C, the standards specify the maximum length of string literals for portable programs. Is there a similar specification for Scheme?

Comment: The current standard is "R7RS small": https://small.r7rs.org/

Comment: I think it is implementation specific.

Answer (score 0):

It is *implementation defined*.

This does not result in direct way as in ISO9899 but by deduction.

In the [small report](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf), in `6.2.3. Implementation restrictions`, we can see:

> An implementation of Scheme must support exact in-
> tegers throughout the range of numbers permitted as
> indexes of lists, vectors, bytevectors, and strings or
> that result from computing the length of one of these.

On the other hand, above that statement, we can see:

> Implementations of Scheme are not required to implement
> the whole tower of subtypes given in section 6.2.1, but they
> ***must implement a coherent subset*** consistent with both
> the purposes of the implementation and the spirit of the
> Scheme language.

This is all what is imposed -- to be logically sound what it's implemented, it does not impose for unlimited arithmetics, as it follows:

> It is recommended, but not required, that implementations
> support exact integers and exact rationals of practically
> unlimited size and precision,

Comment: This tells you limits on strings, not on literal strings: it's easily possible that one should be larger than the other.

Comment: @ignisvolens `length` must apply on literal as well.  You can deduce about string literals from the same statements, they must obey `length`, so they are not allowed to be larger than the maximum integer that can be expressed in the implementation.  There is no higher limit for integers as well.  Apart from that, there is no restriction for a longest string or string literal in the specification. Also, there is written in the paper that for any string generated or explicit in program.

Comment: No-one is disputing that the *maximum* size of objects indexed by integers cannot be larger than the largest representable integer, or equivalently that the implementation must have large enough exact integers to index any such indexable object.  But the maximum size may be *smaller*, and the maximum length of literal strings may be different than the maximum length of strings constructed by the program.  In CL, for instance, they are (although the language specifies no specific limits on literal strings, there are limits which apply to both literal and program-constructed strings).

Comment: @ignisvolens Correct, that is what I mean.  The only restriction is the longest string MUST be smaller than the biggest integer, and there is no constraint for the biggest integer. Also, there is no link between the length of generated strings and fixed strings.  Both MUST be shorter than MAXINT.  This is all the standard conveys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to test it:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

size="${1-1MB}"
scm="${2-bigstr_$size.scm}"

if [[ ! -f "$scm" ]]; then
  (
    exec > "$scm"
    printf '(define bigstr "'
    tr -dc '[:alpha:]' < /dev/urandom |
      dd iflag=fullblock status=none bs="$size" count=1
    printf '")\n'
    printf '(display (string-length bigstr))\n'
    printf '(newline)\n'
  )
fi

printf 'String size: %s\n' "$size"

printf 'Petite Chez Scheme %s: ' \
       "$(petite --version 2>&1)"
petite --script "$scm" 2>/dev/null || echo fail

printf 'Chicken Scheme %s: ' \
       "$(csi -release)"
csi -qs "$scm" 2>/dev/null || echo fail

printf 'Guile Scheme %s: ' \
       "$(guile -c '(format #t "~a\n" (version))')"
guile --no-auto-compile "$scm" 2>/dev/null || echo fail

printf 'Gambit Scheme %s: ' \
       "$(gsi -v | sed -n 's/^v\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/p')"
gsi "$scm" 2>/dev/null || echo fail

printf 'MIT/GNU Scheme %s: ' \
       "$(mit-scheme --version | sed -n 's/.*Release \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/p')"
mit-scheme --quiet --load "$scm" </dev/null 2>/dev/null || echo fail

printf 'Racket Scheme %s: ' \
       "$(racket -e '(display (version))')"
racket --script "$scm" 2>/dev/null || echo fail

printf 'Gauche Scheme %s: ' \
       "$(gosh -V | sed -n 's/^(version "\([^"]*\)")/\1/p')"
gosh "$scm" 2>/dev/null || echo fail
```

On my Debian Schemes work with 10MB but start crashing with 100MB.

```
String size: 100MB
Petite Chez Scheme 9.5.4: 100000000
Chicken Scheme 5.2.0: fail
Guile Scheme 2.2.7: 100000000
Gambit Scheme 4.9.3: 100000000
MIT/GNU Scheme 10.1.11: ;Aborting!: out of memory
fail
Racket Scheme 7.9: 100000000
Gauche Scheme 0.9.10: 100000000
```

Be careful with MIT/GNU Scheme, it is extremely slow.

Comment: You test an implementation, the question is about the restriction imposed by the language, not by some or some implementation :).  You can even do more than that -- paste the explicit code of the garbage collector that allocates an object but this also does not answer OP's question ;).

Comment: @alinsoar The answer is: there is not limit in R7RS. All you can do is: test implementation limits. And the implementation limit is the more important limit. Implementations may not fulfill specifications.

Comment: Correct, it is implementation defined, as the integers have no imposed low-limit and the length must be represented as an integer.

Comment: Wouldn't it work in MIT/GNU Scheme if you had more memory on your machine? Ie. you are just checking which language has slightly more overhead.

Comment: @Sylwester I have 1.5 GB free memory. Should be enough to store 100 MB. Even as 4 byte Unicode.

Comment: In `mit-scheme` correctly you run it so: `cat program.scm | mit-scheme --options`.  Mit-scheme starts by default with some very modest limits.  To change the default limits you need to set ``--heap num-1k-blocks`` for your need or other example `--stack NEW/LIMIT` in case you need a deep nontail recursion.

Comment: Your way of calling mit-scheme means to start interactive mode after having loaded your program before.

Answer (score 0):

Brief answer: no, there is no such limit specified.  As such any limit is a limitation of the implementation.